# I want to know how to pass values after doing a rest api function, without storing data in MongDB

Tags: mongodb, rest

I get details from user and call a rest api function and validate that details. But after that I need to pass the all details to payment page without storing values in my MongoDB. After the payment is successful those details need to be stored.

I am implementing frontend using react and html. I take telephone number and identity card number as valuable data. When I press the submit button the system will validate the user and show the output in the next page. I want to pass the telephone number and identity card number to next page without storing it in a mongodb.

```
render() {
    return <div className="container card">
        <div className="card-body">
            <h4 className="card-title">Buyer Details</h4>
            <h6 className="card-subtitle mb-2 text-muted">We offer a discount for Government Employees by using your NIC number </h6><br/>
        <form>
            <div className="row">
                <div className="col-md-4 form-group">
                    <label htmlFor="name">First Name*</label>
                    <input type="text" className="form-control" id="fname" maxLength={100} placeholder="First Name" required/>
                </div>
                <div className="col-md-4 form-group">
                    <label htmlFor="name">Last Name*</label>
                    <input type="text" className="form-control" id="lname" maxLength={100} placeholder="Last Name" required/>
                </div>
            </div>

            <div className="row">
            <div className="col-md-4 form-group">
                <label htmlFor="telephone">Telephone*</label>
                <input type="tel" className="form-control" id="telephone" maxLength={10} minLength={10} placeholder="Your telephone number" required/>
            </div>
            <div className="col-md-4 form-group">
                <label htmlFor="telephone">Email*</label>
                <input type="email" className="form-control" id="telephone" placeholder="myemail@example.com" required/>
            </div>
            </div>

            <div className="row">
            <div className="form-group col-md-8">
                <label htmlFor="address">Address*</label>
                <input type="text" className="form-control" id="address1"
                       placeholder="Address Line 1 " required/><br/>
                <input type="text" className="form-control" id="address2" placeholder="City" required/>
            </div>
            </div>

            <div className="row">
                <div className="form-group col-md-4">
                    <label htmlFor="address">Gender*</label>
                    <select className="custom-select" required>
                        <option value="">--</option>
                        <option value="1">Male</option>
                        <option value="2">Female</option>
                    </select>
                </div>
                <div className="col-md-4 form-group">
                    <label htmlFor="telephone">NIC no*</label>
                    <input type="text" className="form-control" id="telephone" maxLength={10} minLength={10} placeholder="XXXXXXXXXV" required/>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div className="row">
                <div className="form-group col-md-4">
                <label htmlFor="telephone">Fields with * are required</label>
                </div>
            </div>
            <button type="submit" className="btn btn-info">Proceed</button>


        </form>
        </div>


    </div>;
}
```

Comment: Provide some reactjs component code also

Comment: I updated. Hope It might help you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you are doing an antipattern in the backend section.
Why don't you want to save the transaction in MongoDB? You create a transaction record on your DB; then in your payment page callback, you update the transaction status to either COMPLETED or FAILED.
This isn't related to react or Frontend.

Comment: You are suggesting to add the buyer details and after completing his/her payment, I should update the status of the particular record to pass. Until that the status of the payment is failed. Right?

Comment: Nope, it's PENDING then it gets changed to COMPLETED or FAILED. also, store a timestamp for the creation time of the record. If say 10 minutes has passed the payment creation time and status is PENDING then it should be considered FAILED.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using a central store like redux, you can update the state. and again get it in next page. Or else you can keep that in browser session storage and retrieve back.

Comment: Seems like it's a good solution but new to me. Can you please provide any resource for a scenario for that?

Comment: Check This example it will give you some idea about the redux store. https://codesandbox.io/s/wwnpn034z7 along with this you can go to redux official docs.